# Write text file to pipeline

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have multiple spiders in a single scrapy project.

I want to write a separate output text file for each spider with spider name and time stamp.

When I had a single spider I was creating file in `__init` method but now I am trying like this, **upromise** will generate two output files while other will only one.

```
class MallCrawlerPipeline(object):

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.aWriter = csv.writer(open('../%s_%s.txt' % (spider.name, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")), 'wb'),
        delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    self.aWriter.writerow(['mall', 'store', 'bonus', 'per_action', 'more_than','up_to', 'deal_url', 'category'])

    if 'upromise' in spider.name:
        self.cWriter = csv.writer(
            open('../%s_coupons_%s.txt' % (spider.name, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")), 'wb'),
            delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        self.cWriter.writerow(['mall', 'store', 'bonus', 'per_action', 'more_than','up_to', 'deal_url', 'category'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.aWriter.writerow([item['mall'], item['store'], item['bonus'], item['per_action'],
                           item['more_than'], item['up_to'], item['deal_url'], item['category']])

    return item
```

But I am facing this bug:

```
 File "C:\Users\akhter\Dropbox\akhter\mall_crawler\mall_crawler\pipelines.py", line 24, in process_item
    self.aWriter.writerow([item['mall'], item['store'], item['bonus'], item['per_action'],
exceptions.AttributeError: 'MallCrawlerPipeline' object has no attribute 'aWriter'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is aWriter defined?  Should this object be inheriting from something other than `object` perhaps?

Comment: @sr2222 thanks for your reply but, i am very sorry i don't have much grep on python, can you please give me a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys i found an answer i just need to give a signal otherwise spider_opened never call like this in **init** method. still open for suggestions

```
def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're always running `obj.spider_opened(...)` before `obj.process_item(...)`? It seems you're not, as after the first method call that attribute should have been added to the object.

If the first method call is always needed perhaps it makes sense to move it to `__init__` or call it from there, by the way.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Eduardo lvanec, if i moved this to __init__ how  can i access spider name over there ?