# Scrapy pipeline open_sider not being called

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113275/scrapy-pipeline-spider-opened-and-spider-closed-not-being-called), and I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608391/write-text-file-to-pipeline), but [the official Scrapy page on pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) mention nothing about signals.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import log

class Sqlite3StorePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'wtf'
        dispatcher.connect(self.open_spider, signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.close_spider, signals.spider_closed)

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        print 'wtf2'
        ...
```

When I run my spider using the command `scrapy crawl <spider name>`, I only see "wtf" but not "wtf2" being output.

How can I get my `open_spider` function to be called?

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with scrapy right now, and I've had odd issues with stdout so far.  Have you tried logging 'wtf'2? i.e.

```
    def open_spider(self,spider):
        spider.log('wtf2 from spider %s' % spider.name)
```

Comment: Huh, interesting. I tried it with spider.log as well. No luck there. I'm pretty sure that function is not called because if it was, my database would be initialized in a certain way that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of scrapy are you using? the signals API was [changed](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/1e12c92b8f4114b75bac7bed714d2e59e12b701d) around 7 months ago, affecting 0.15 and later.

Comment: I'm using Scrapy 14.4. Should I upgrade to the development branch?